# printing linked list with pointers with python

Tags: python, linked-list

Im a python beginner and trying to create a function the prints out the values of a linked list with a pointer '->' I created a solution, but it appears its failing on of my testers, and idk why.

```
class LinkNode:
def __init__(self,value,nxt=None):
    assert isinstance(nxt, LinkNode) or nxt is None
    self.value = value
    self.next = nxt

def print_list(lst):
    """
    >>> print_list(LinkNode(3, None))
    3 -> None
    """
    temp = lst
    while temp:
       print(temp.value, sep = '', end=' -> ')
       temp = temp.next
```

Everytime i run it it creates the same output, and looks the same but there is an error saying:

```
 Test Failed: '3 -> ' != '3 -> None\n'
 - 3 -> 
 + 3 -> None
```

Im not sure what the \n is trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` is the escape code for a "new line".

The `sep` argument doesn't do anything unless you print more than one item in the same print call.

You also aren't printing the final `None`. Do so after the while loop.

```
def print_list(lst):
    """
    >>> print_list(LinkNode(3, None))
    3 -> None
    """
    temp = lst
    while temp:
       print(temp.value, end=' -> ')  # you don't need sep here.
       temp = temp.next
    print(temp)
```

Comment: oops sorry, i changed my parameter lst to x by accident when i was trying to put my code into stack over flow. @gilch

Comment: what do you mean by printing final None?

Comment: @michael The example in the docstring shows `3 -> None`, but you're only ever printing `temp.value`, not `temp.next` where the None lives. There's no way for `None` to print.

Comment: I see, more or less, so adding a print after the while loop should print the None?

Comment: @michael please upvote and accept the answer if it meets your needs instead of a "thank you" comment.